# submin add an exsiting repository

Tags: python, linux, svn

When I change the svn_dir to an exsiting svn repostory, the error came out.

```
External command 'svnadmin' failed: svnadmin: E165002: 
'/home/work/fanbo/svnuse/svn/zz' is an existing repository
```

I only know how to new an submin web website, but I don't know how to config it contact with an existing svn project.